# Writing my first systemcall(for learning kernel development) in freebsd

Tags: c, operating-system, filesystems, freebsd, system-calls

So I have just started customizing the FreeBSD kernel, but unfortunately the resources available for FreeBSD development are scarce .

Im writing a systemcall in which should read a file(optionally), read the blocks of physical memory according to input and write the results into another file(generally "filename.results")

my problems are:

Standard C libraries: it seems to be that they are unavailable for kernel module programming so how should I replace the functions such as write and read(and strlen and some others in string.h)?

Malloc function: it seems that it accepts 3 inputs instead of 1, and I have no idea how to fill the 2nd variable even after reading the man page(tried FOO but returns symlink error).

Also I was interested in any other topics u think they are useful for this routine.

Comment: I myself don't know much about kernel development, but I've read a little about it. About the functions from C libraries and malloc. The kernel itself should have its owns variants of all functions which is needed by it. Try search the kernel code for the functions you'll need.

Just as a hit try check this link out. https://www.freebsd.org/doc/en/articles/geom-class/kernelprog.html

You won't come long without going through some of the kernel source code. 
Good luck..

Comment: Also i found this document which describes some different functions in the file called sys/libkern.h

http://www.leidinger.net/FreeBSD/src_doc/libkern.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I've said that I got the answer.
So for future reads I'm just leaving it here.

MALLOC: you need to define your own memory description(or use an existing one) in order to be able to locate it, that's a POSIX standard and its for sanity check purposes.

as for the other things, for the fact that standard c libraries are not available in kernel mode, the kernel variant of them is likely available in libkern (open /sys/libkern), and they will be all available once you implement it(say uprintf, strlen and stuff), if its not there you have to call the relying module by implementing them in your header file(say for FILE interaction you need to include the I/O module located in /sys/(dir)) since you ARE in kernel mode it doesn't create a problem.(also note that those functions are well implemented so you wont likely face a kernel crash.)

As an obvious fact you have to copy the buffer from user memory to kernel memory in order to do modifications on it, and copy it back when you are done.

one last thing, in order to implement your systemcall via sysproto auto build you need to include it as well(and add your syscall to the list). and don't forget to include your file in the source file configuration file (located in /sys/(dir) again).

Answer (score 0):

In case of malloc, do "man 9 malloc".  The "9" here means section describing kernel functions, userland malloc is described in section 3.

Comment: well I think I got this one, after reading a book titled freebsd device drivers its pretty much clear to me now.